# What's considered a step in Pokemon?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've been breeding a lot of Pokemon recently and I've been doing the loop around the Battle Resort, which led to me wondering: what is considered to be a step in the Pokemon breeding world?

Is it now calculated through how long you've been walking or how many steps you've taken? I ask this because on the Battle Resort loop there are three sand pits that hinder how fast you go, does this also hinder my egg hatch time?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Push a direction on the d-pad once. That's a step.

While your movement is unrestricted on the bike or while using the circle pad, the game world is grid-based, and moving from a square to an adjacent one is a step.

So yes, sand pits and anything that slows you down will also slow down an Egg's hatching.

Comment: Of note, simply spinning around in your current square without leaving it will not count as a step. Could be useful to add in there.